# How to add SSL with curl url Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: ubuntu, curl, ssl

While running a twitter api from curl in ubuntu terminal it asked me to use SSL
after searching for it i tried -

```
sudo curl -s https://localhost:8080/tweets/HLaddha

sudo curl -k https://localhost:8080/tweets/HLaddha

sudo curl --cert-type SSL https://localhost:8080/tweets/HLaddha

openssl s_client -connect facebook.com:443 |tee logfile
sudo curl --cacert logfile https://localhost:8080/tweets/HLaddha
```

But i could not find the correct usage. Can anyone tell me how do i do it the error message i get is -

```
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to localhost:8080
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, e.g. what has localhost:8080 to do with twitter API. Are you sure that you even have https on localhost:8080?

Comment: No I don't have https on local host that's why I want to make a secure request from curl and test the script of my api. And that's why I asked how to get SSL certificate when using curl of kind or emulate it

Comment: There is no emulation for certificates, you have to create certificates and setup a server so that it uses them. But there is already enough documentation out there how to do this.